# Conditionally separate daily data based on monthly mean values

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have daily data and want to separate months with mean less than 1 from rest of data. Do something on daily data (with mean greater than 1). The important thing is not to touch daily values with monthly mean less than 1.

I have used  `aggregate(file,as.yearmon,mean)` to get monthly mean but failing to grasp on how to use it to filter specific month's daily values from analysis. Any suggestion to start would be highly appreciative.

I have reproduced data using a small subset of it and `dput`:

`structure(list(V1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.43, 0.24, 0, 1.06, 0, 0, 0,  1.57, 1.26, 1.34, 0, 0, 0, 2.09, 0, 0, 0.24)), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA,  20L), class = "data.frame")`

A snippet of code I am using:

```
library(zoo)
file <- read.table("text.txt")
x_daily <- zooreg(file, start=as.Date("2000-01-01"))
x1_daily <- x_daily[]
con_daily <- subset(x1_daily, aggregate(x1_daily,as.yearmon,mean) > 1 )
```

Comment: take a look at `?subset`.  You can also use `dput` to give us a better example of your data..

Comment: How do you suggest i use `dput`?

Comment: I read my text file `ifile <- read.table(file.txt)` and then `dput(ifile)` gave me a long list of values in file with these at the end ` .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10950L))`

Comment: See this answer to "how to make a great reproducible example" http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1727133

Comment: I got following:
`structure(list(V1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.43, 0.24, 0, 1.06, 0, 0, 0, 
1.57, 1.26, 1.34, 0, 0, 0, 2.09, 0, 0, 0.24)), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
`

Comment: Yes, but that can't be the right data; it has no factor called `as.yearmon` !

Comment: Ibe, your code and example should be completely self contained so that we don't need to guess what things are. [The link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) that @AndrewMacDonald posted, explains why this is important - not least is getting you the answer that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create some sample data:

```
feb2012 <- data.frame(year=2012, month=2, day=1:28, data=rnorm(28))
feb2013 <- data.frame(year=2013, month=2, day=1:28, data=rnorm(28) + 10)
jul2012 <- data.frame(year=2012, month=7, day=1:31, data=rnorm(31) + 10)
jul2013 <- data.frame(year=2013, month=7, day=1:31, data=rnorm(31) + 10)
d <- rbind(feb2012, feb2013, jul2012, jul2013)
```

You can get an aggregate of the `data` column by month like this:

```
> a <- aggregate(d$data, list(year=d$year, month=d$month), mean)
> a
  year month           x
1 2012     2  0.09704817
2 2013     2  9.93354271
3 2012     7 10.19073868
4 2013     7  9.78324133
```

Perhaps not the best way, but an easy way to filter the `d` data frame by the mean of the corresponding year and month is to work with a temporary data frame that merges `d` and `a`, like this:

```
work <- merge(d, a)
subset(work, x > 1)
```

I hope this will help you get started!

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. I have 28 years of data which means 28 Jan months. Is it possible to bind all months recursively just like you only did for feb and jul?

Comment: The only issue I see here is that data is for 28 years which means 336 months. If I have to type all months like `feb2012` `feb2013` etc then it will consume a lot of time. I need to do it automatically in code.

Comment: I generated the sample data frame above in a way that's easy to understand and reproduce. I don't know how your actual data is organized, and you did not explain that in your question. If you have difficulty getting your data into a similar data frame, it would be better to post a new question, focusing on that part.